# No perfect way to detect device orientation on iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

**EDIT: The given answer works on the device, but beware it fails on the simulator.**

When my iPad starts up, I show a loading label, centered in the middle of the screen. I set its autoresizingMask so it recenters on orientation change.

As the app starts up, the label's text changes, so I want to recenter the label based on its new length. However, the following piece of code doesn't center the label correctly:

```
- (void) setLabelText:(NSString*)text {
  CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(500,20);
  CGSize expectedLabelSize = [text sizeWithFont:loadingLabel.font
                              constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                  lineBreakMode:loadingLabel.lineBreakMode];
  loadingLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-expectedLabelSize.width/2,
                                  loadingLabel.frame.origin.y, 
                                  expectedLabelSize.width, 
                                  loadingLabel.frame.size.height);
  loadingLabel.text = text;
}
```

I also considered checking [[UIDevice currentDevice]orientation], and if the iPad is in landscape mode, then I'd use self.view.frame.size.height to set the xOrigin of the label.

However, if the device is face up or face down, (and not landscape or portrait) then this method fails. I also have a lastOrientation variable in my appDelegate, which remembers if the app is in landscape or portrait, even when face up or face down, based on the device's last known orientation. However, at start-up, this variable isn't necessarily set.

Is there some simple solution I am missing here, so I can resize and center my label?

**EDIT: I tried checking UIStatusBarOrientation based on the advice posted, but it doesn't work:**

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
    || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
  NSLog(@"landscape");  
  width = self.view.frame.size.height;
} else {
  NSLog(@"portrait");   
}
```

This always logs portrait, at least on start-up, on the simulator.

Comment: Umm, what do you mean "if the device is face up or face down, (and not landscape or portrait) then this method fails."?

Comment: Does checking the status bar orientation help?

Comment: @ColdLogic - an iPad can be portrait, landscape, or face up, or face down. When it is face up, it isn't necessarily portrait or landscape. You can demonstrate this as follows - place the iPad on a table in Portrait, then rotate it. You can see that the device doesn't become landscape, and this makes knowing how to orient things tricky.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using loadingLabel.textAlignment =  UITextAlignmentCenter?

Comment: @Tommy Good question, and yes... I position a loading spinner to the left of the text, so I need to know the left edge of the label

Comment: Ummm, the method doesn't "fail". It's not suppose to do anything because there is no orientation change when you rotate the device while it is flat (face up or face down as you put it). This happens on every device (rotate an iPhone while it is set flat, and the orientation will not change). Unless I misunderstood what you stated, there is no way to not "fail". To answer your overall question of "No perfect way to detect device orientation on iPad", there is a perfect way, and that's with the [[UIApplication currentDevice] orientation].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]`

Comment: This seemed like good advice, so I tried it, but it didn't work. See my code edit :(

Comment: You're checking if the iPad is in right and left orientation at the same time. Use the or operator, `||` isntead of the and operator, `&&`.

Comment: I just noticed that too, and tried the ||, but it fails as well. Edited the answer again.

Comment: Have you added all the supportedDeviceOrientations to your Info.plist?

Comment: Yes, added all four to the plist.

Comment: Hmm, and you've implemented `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and are returning `YES` correct?

Comment: Actually, this method works on the device, just not the simulator it seems, so I am using it and marking it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome! Good to know that this fails in the simulator (for now).

Comment: I found that this didn't work. As I recall, it used to. But I just came by an orientation bug that I thought I had fixed. The statusBarOrientation method is returning FaceUp instead of portrait or landscape

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick to solve the FaceUp orientation issue!!!

Delay the orientation check till AFTER the app has started running, then set variables, view sizes, etc.!!!

```
//CODE

- (void)viewDidLoad {

  [super viewDidLoad];

  //DELAY
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 
                     target:self 
                     selector:@selector(delayedCheck) 
                     userInfo:nil 
                     repeats:NO];

}


-(void)delayedCheck{

  //DETERMINE ORIENTATION
  if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ){
      FACING = @"PU";
  }
  if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown ){
      FACING = @"PD";
  }
  if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft ){
      FACING = @"LL";
  }
  if( [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ){
      FACING = @"LR";
  } 
  //DETERMINE ORIENTATION

  //START
  [self setStuff];
  //START

}


-(void)setStuff{

  if( FACING == @"PU" ){
          //logic for Portrait
  }
  else
  if( FACING == @"PD" ){
          //logic for PortraitUpsideDown
  }
  else{ 
  if( FACING == @"LL"){
          //logic for LandscapeLeft
  }
  else
  if( FACING == @"LR" ){
          //logic for LandscapeRight
  }

}

//CODE
```

You can addSubviews, position elements, etc. in the 'setStuff' function ... anything that would initially depend on the orientation!!!

:D

-Chris Allinson