# iPad - Change image depending on device orientation (Portrait or Landscape)

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, device-orientation

Inside my `viewDidLoad` method, I am applying a "loading image" that appears until a `webView` had completed loading. I would like to specify a different loading image depending on which orientation (portrait or landscape) the iPad is in.

I found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174084/no-perfect-way-to-detect-device-orientation-on-ipad) which is what I based my code from.

My code is shown below. (this is all contained within my `viewDidLoad` method). This only works in **Portrait** mode at the moment. Any idea why my landscape code isn't being called? Please help!

```
//detect if iPad    
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
//if in Portrait Orientation
            if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
                loadingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"webView-load-image-Portrait~ipad.png"];
                loadingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:loadingImage];
                loadingImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"webView-load-image-Portrait~ipad.png"],
                                                    nil];
            }
//if in Landscape Orientation
            if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
               || [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
                loadingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"webView-load-image-Landscape~ipad.png"];
                loadingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:loadingImage];
                loadingImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"webView-load-image-Landscape~ipad.png"],
                                                    nil];
            }

        }
```

**UPDATE**

I know you're supposed to be able to use image file name modifiers so that the device will automatically pull the correct image. I have tried putting webView-load-image.png in my app images folder with all the correct extensions (and removing the `-Portrait~ipad` from the file name):

- webView-load-image~iphone.png
- webView-load-image@2x~iphone.png
- webView-load-image-Landscape~ipad.png
- webView-load-image-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
- webView-load-image-Portrait~ipad.png
- webView-load-image-Portrait@2x~ipad.png

and it is still not working :(

Comment: Are you changing the orientation of the iPad during the loading process?

Comment: No. The iPad is in landscape orientation, and then the app is launched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Here's what worked for me in case anyone else is having the same issue:

```
//ViewController.h
@interface ViewController : GAITrackedViewController {
    // ...other code
    UIImage *loadingImage;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *loadingImageView;


//ViewController.m
    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        ...bunch of other code....

    // Subscribe to device orientation notifications, and set "orientation" - will return a number 1-5, with 5 being "unknown".
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;

    //**************** Start Add Static loading image  ****************/
        //if iPhone
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        loadingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"webView-load-image~iphone.png"];
        loadingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:loadingImage];
            loadingImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                [UIImage imageNamed:@"webView-load-image~iphone.png"],
                                                nil];
        }

       if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
           if(orientation == 3 || orientation == 4) {
               loadingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"webView-load-image-Landscape~ipad.png"];
               loadingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:loadingImage];
               loadingImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                   [UIImage imageNamed:@"webView-load-image-Landscape~ipad.png"],
                                                   nil];
               NSLog(@"Set webView-load-image iPhone Landscape");

           }
           if(orientation == 5) {
               NSLog(@"Set webView-load-image UNKNOWN");
           }
           if(orientation == 1) {
                loadingImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"webView-load-image-Portrait~ipad.png"];
                loadingImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:loadingImage];
                loadingImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"webView-load-image-Portrait~ipad.png"],
                                                    nil];
                NSLog(@"Set webView-load-image iPad Portrait");
            }


        }

        [self.view addSubview:loadingImageView];
        // End Add Static loading image
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked back at an App I worked on a while ago and I was doing something similar.  This is how I got it to work...

I created a method to handle the change in orientation...

```
BOOL isPortraitView = YES;

@implementation MyViewController
{
    // a bunch of code...

    - (void)setOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))
        {
            isPortraitView = YES;

            // do other stuff
        }
        else
        {
            isPortraitView = NO;

            // do other stuff
        }
    }

    // other code...
}
```

It accepts a `UIInterfaceOrientation` value so you don't have to use the status bar method (if I remember correctly, that method is not the best/most predictable).  I also store a class level Boolean value for quick reference.  I then call this on the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [self setOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}
```

This can also handle an orientation change during the load process.

Comment: When I implement this code in Xcode, on the line `isPortraitView = YES;` I get an error "Use of undeclared identifier "isPortraitView""  What do I need to do?

Comment: Add `BOOL isPortraiView;` above the if statement

Comment: I would add it to the .h file to it is available class wide.

Comment: Updated my answer.  I looked back at my code and saw that I just declared it above the implementation so all the methods within have access to the variable.  Does that help?

Comment: Ok... so I put this before my `viewDidLoad` method. Will this work when app is launched? For example, I want this code to run before the app appears if possible. If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Glad you figured it out, but for goodness sake, remove the hardcoded numeric values for orientation!! There are enums declared for this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDeviceOrientation) {
    UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
    UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,            // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
    UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,  // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,       // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,      // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,              // Device oriented flat, face up
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown             // Device oriented flat, face down
};
```

and

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIInterfaceOrientation) {
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait           = UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown = UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft      = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight     = UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
};
```

And you should probably check your viewController's `interfaceOrientation` rather than device orientation.

Also, check out the following macros:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)
UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)
```

Your code should look more like:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation) {
    // show landscape image
} else {
    // show portrait image
}
```

Comment: I tried something like your code and it didn't work for some reason...? So unless you can implement it as my answer shows, I'm stuck with mine :( (I'm a newbie)